# issue adding items to NSArray from other Array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, twitter

I am trying to add the Instagram pictures to the same array as the Twitter Tweets but when i load the app the tweets only show after the 8th row.:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return totalFeed.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)  {
        NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *created = [tweet objectForKey:@"created_at"];
        NSLog(@"%@", created);
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
        NSString *name = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];



        cell.textLabel.text = text;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", name];
        return cell;
        if (name == NULL) {
            NSLog(@"Tweet Doesent Exist");
        }
    }else {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InstagramCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        NSDictionary *entry = instaPics[indexPath.row];
        NSString *imageUrlString = entry[@"images"][@"low_resolution"][@"url"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
        return cell;
    }

}


- (void)fetchTweets {
    self.twitterClient = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"] key:@"4oFCF0AjP4PQDUaCh5RQ" secret:@"NxAihESVsdUXSUxtHrml2VBHA0xKofYKmmGS01KaSs"];

    [self.twitterClient authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath:@"/oauth/request_token" userAuthorizationPath:@"/oauth/authorize" callbackURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"floadt://success"] accessTokenPath:@"/oauth/access_token" accessMethod:@"POST" scope:nil success:^(AFOAuth1Token *accessToken, id responseObject) {
        [self.twitterClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self.twitterClient getPath:@"statuses/home_timeline.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
            [responseArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@", obj);
                tweets = responseArray;
                [self updateArrays];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    //[[TwitterClient sharedClient] getTimeline];
}

- (void)fetchInstagramPics {
    NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL *status = [user boolForKey:@"isInstagramLoggedIn"];
    if (status) {
        [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:@"users/self/feed"
                                     parameters:nil
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                            // NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
                                            self.timelineResponse = responseObject;
                                            [self updateArrays];
                                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                                        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
                                        }];
    }


}

- (void)updateArrays {
    instaPics = self.timelineResponse[@"data"];
    totalFeed = [instaPics arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tweets];
    instaPics = [totalFeed mutableCopy];
    tweets = [totalFeed mutableCopy];
}

- (void)fetchTimeline {
    [self fetchInstagramPics];
    [self fetchTweets];
    [self updateArrays];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The Problem is that the posts are a lot below where they are supposed to be in the `indexpath.row`

[image: Screenshot of the App]

Answer (score 1):

I think reloading data on main queue can fix the issue.

Try this in both the fetchInstagramPics and fetchTweets methods:

> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>     [self.tableView reloadData]; });

and let me know whether it works.

Comment: If you find this answer to be useful, please tick the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are tying to achieve but seems to be the way your are forming your array is not quite right.

```
 - (void)updateArrays {

    totalFeed = [instaPics arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tweets]; // concatinates two arrays.
    // NLog your total feed and see the behaviour 
    instaPics = [totalFeed mutableCopy];
    tweets = [totalFeed mutableCopy];
}
```

If you want to get tweets and Instagram in alternate cell like I have attached in image 
Just don't sum up  instaPics & tweets with totalFeed. Use them independently. 
[image: Alternate tweets & instagram pics]

```
 - (void)updateArrays {

    totalFeed = [instaPics arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tweets]; // concatinates two arrays.

// rmeove this

//    instaPics = [totalFeed mutableCopy];
//    tweets = [totalFeed mutableCopy];
}
```

Your total feed contains alternate data structure for tweets and instagram pics.
and instaPics & tweets array are redundant copy of that.

If you want to keep them in same cell then create once cell and use totalFeed array without %2 condition.